# WSDL Soap Exception in webservices

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Does anyone know what this error means? I've read that it could be PHP version issue. Could it also be due to permissions? Or say.. like a firewall?

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 
'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime' [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:
protected] => /person/ok/my_library/Zend/Soap/aplace.php [line:protected] => 51 [trace
:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /person/ok/my_library/Zend/Soap/Client
/aplace.php [line] => 51 [function] => SoapClient [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => 
Array ( [0] => http://myWSDL:7001/web/10/Intw?WSDL [1] => Array ( [encoding]
 => UTF-8 [soap_version] => 2 [trace] => 1 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /person/ok/my_library/
 Zend/Soap/Client.php [line] => 1024 [function] => __construct [class] => Zend_Soap_Client_aplace
 [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Zend_Soap_Client Object ( [_encoding:protected] 
 => UTF-8 [_classmap:protected] => [_faultExceptions:protected] => Array ( ) [_soapVersion:protected] 
 => 2 [_uri:protected] => [_location:protected] => [_style:protected] => [_use:protected] => 
 [_login:protected] => [_password:protected] => [_proxy_host:protected] => [_proxy_port:protected] 
 => [_proxy_login:protected] => [_proxy_password:protected] => [_local_cert:protected] => 
 [_passphrase:protected] => [_compression:protected] => [_connection_timeout:protected] => 
 [_stream_context:protected] => [_features:protected] => [_cache_wsdl:protected] => 
 [_user_agent:protected] => [_wsdl:protected] => http://myWSDL:7001/web/101/Intw?WSDL 
 [_soapClient:protected] => [_lastMethod:protected] => [_soapInputHeaders:protected] => Array ( ) 
 [_permanentSoapInputHeaders:protected] => Array ( ) [_soapOutputHeaders:protected] => Array ( ) ) 
 [1] => _doRequest ) [1] => http://myWSDL:7001/web/101/Intw?WSDL [2] => 
 Array ( [encoding] => UTF-8 [soap_version] => 2 [trace] => 1 ) ) ) [2] => 
 Array ( [file] => /my_library/place.php [line] => 
 1180 [function] => _initSoapClientObject [class] => Zend_Soap_Client 
 [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [file] => /my_library/place.php 
 [line] => 1104 [function] => getSoapClient [class] => Zend_Soap_Client [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [4] => 
 Array ( [file] => /some/path/to/my/file.php [line] => 
 149 [function] => __call [class] => Zend_Soap_Client [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => command [1] => 
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [arg0] => Array ( [Username] => myUsername:) [Password] => 
 myPassword:) [InputField] => Summary [ItemId] => 9999999 ) ) ) ) ) [5] => 
 Array ( [file] => /some/path/to/my/file.php 
 [line] => 149 [function] => command [class] => Zend_Soap_Client [type] => -> [args] => 
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [arg0] => Array ( [Username] => myUsername:) [Password] => myPassword:) [InputField] => 
 Summary [ItemId] => 9999999 ) ) ) ) [6] => Array ( [file] => /some/path/to/my/file.php 
 [line] => 256 [function] => getPickFieldValue [class] => Code_Tracker_PriNvcProcessController [type] => -> [args] => 
 Array ( [0] => Dev Task Component ) ) [7] => Array ( [file] => /person/ok/my_library/Zend/Controller/Action.php [line] => 513 [function] => 
 mksFormAction [class] => Code_Tracker_PriNvcProcessController [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [8] => 
 Array ( [file] => /some/other/path/to/another/file.php [line] => 289 [function] => 
 dispatch [class] => Zend_Controller_Action [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => mksFormAction ) ) [9] => 
 Array ( [file] => /person/ok/my_library/Zend/Controller/Front.php [line] => 954 [function] => dispatch [class] => 
 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( [_paramSources:protected] => 
 Array ( [0] => _GET [1] => _POST ) [_requestUri:protected] => /yet/another/path/to/a/js/form?code_id=706 [_baseUrl:protected] => 
 [_basePath:protected] => [_pathInfo:protected] => /yet/another/path/to/a/js/form [_params:protected] => Array ( [module] => 
 code_tracker [controller] => pri-nvc-process [action] => mks-form ) [_rawBody:protected] => [_aliases:protected] => Array ( ) 
 [_dispatched:protected] => 1 [_module:protected] => code_tracker [_moduleKey:protected] => module [_controller:protected] => 
 pri-nvc-process [_controllerKey:protected] => controller [_action:protected] => mks-form [_actionKey:protected] => action ) [1] => 
 Zend_Controller_Response_Http Object ( [_body:protected] => Array ( ) [_exceptions:protected] => Array ( ) [_headers:protected] => Array ( ) 
 [_headersRaw:protected] => Array ( ) [_httpResponseCode:protected] => 200 [_isRedirect:protected] => [_renderExceptions:protected] => 
 [headersSentThrowsException] => 1 ) ) ) [10] => Array ( [file] => /again/another/path/to/initialize.php [line] => 67 [function] => 
 dispatch [class] => Zend_Controller_Front [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [11] => Array ( [file] => /again/another/path/to/initialize.php 
 [line] => 43 [function] => dispatch [class] => application_Init [type] => :: [args] => Array ( ) ) [12] => Array ( [file] => 
 /again/another/path/to/initialize.php [line] => 55 [function] => init [class] => application_Init [type] => :: [args] => 
 Array ( ) ) [13] => Array ( [file] => /another/path/but/to/html/index.php [line] => 20 [function] => start [class] => 
 application_Init [type] => :: [args] => Array ( ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: 
 Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime' [faultcode] => WSDL )
```

Comment: Try accessing schema location http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime in browser or using curl from the same server you are running this application and see if you can get to it.

Comment: I can get to it in my browser without any issue. Thanks for the response. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could still be proxy (preventing access to schema from your application) but your browser might already be preconfigured for it.

Within your php application, can print log output for the HTTP code returned for that schema location?  Haven't use PHP before but perhaps using HttpClient - something like this: http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/examples.php